# ORDER BY Clause with IF Statment

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, case, mysql-8.0

I am struggling with Order by clause with If statement without If statement it's working correctly. I have two keys points which is of `int` type and date which is of `timestamp` type in my `test` table. I am adding sample data for reference

```
Table Name - test

    id  points    date
    ------------------------
    1   90        2019-12-14 09:01:10
    2   10        2019-12-15 09:01:10
    3   200       2019-12-16 09:01:10
    4   120       2019-12-6 09:01:10
    5   606       2019-12-9 09:01:10
```

So my query

```
SELECT id, points, date FROM test order by points desc
```

Returns

```
    id  points    date
    ------------------------
    5   606       2019-12-9 09:01:10
    3   200       2019-12-16 09:01:10
    4   120       2019-12-6 09:01:10
    1   90        2019-12-14 09:01:10
    2   10        2019-12-15 09:01:10
```

This is the expected result but if I am trying to add `points` in If clause then it sort the points in alphabetic order

Query

```
SELECT id, points, date FROM test order by IF(TRUE, points, date) desc
```

Returns

```
    id  points    date
    ------------------------
    1   90        2019-12-14 09:01:10
    5   606       2019-12-9 09:01:10
    3   200       2019-12-16 09:01:10
    4   120       2019-12-6 09:01:10
    2   10        2019-12-15 09:01:10
```

How can I achieve the result in numeric descending order.

**Expected Result**

```
    id  points    date
    ------------------------
    5   606       2019-12-9 09:01:10
    3   200       2019-12-16 09:01:10
    4   120       2019-12-6 09:01:10
    1   90        2019-12-14 09:01:10
    2   10        2019-12-15 09:01:10
```

**Note**: I am using MYSQL 8.0.21

Comment: IF statement may be used in compound statements (procedures, functions, triggers and so on) only. You mean IF function. Which returns string-type value in your case.

Comment: @Akina, Yaa, I mean If function

Comment: Please formulate desired sorting criteries more clear.

Comment: Please show us the result that you want.

Comment: @GMB I have already add the desired result in my question. My first query returns desired result

Comment: @Akina I want to sort my result on the basis of user input, user can choose, he want to sort the result by points or date field

Comment: What user may input precisely?

Comment: Which result is the wanted result?

Comment: @Akina, My product shows sorting options on the frontend and the user can choose sorting by himself. How he wants to sort the result.

Comment: @jarlh I have updated the expected result in question.

Comment: If so then this is the problem of the output subsystem (which prints the rowset on the display) and it is not related to the database. It is too strange to requery the whole rowset for rows resorting only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> I want to sort my result on the basis of user input, user can choose, he want to sort the result by points or date field

The two columns have different datataypes, so you would need two different levels of sorting. Assuming that user input is given as parameter `:order_col`, that may take value "points" or "date":

```sql
order by 
    case when :order_col = 'points' then points end desc,
    case when :order_col = 'date' then date end desc
```

An alternative would be to turn the date to a number, for example using `unix_timestamp()`: the datatypes are then consistent, and a single level of sorting is sufficient:

```sql
order by case :order_col
    when 'points' then points
    when 'date' then unix_timestamp(date)
end desc
```